# 4 responsive divs are not showing properly on tab and mobile

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create 4 responsive divs for homepage; tried to decreae padding and margin of div not working.divs should be responsive on mobile devices they shpuld move below each one ; two divs appear on tabs; 4 divs on desktop and one div on mobile
i have tried following HTML:

```
 <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flex-item">
        <div class="flex-item-inner">
               <div class="homepage-div homepage-div-shadow">
                <img class="homepage-div-icon"/>
                <h2>Heading</h2>
                <h6>Sub-Heading</h6>
                <p>This is responsive paragraph. Text would not move out of div as below .</p>
                <button class="bttn"><a href="#" role="button">Practice Now</a></button>
               </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
        <div class="flex-item-inner">
               <div class="homepage-div homepage-div-shadow">
                <img class="homepage-div-icon"/>
                <h2>Heading</h2>
                <h6>Sub-Heading</h6>
                <p>This is responsive paragraph. Text would not move out of div as below .</p>
                <button class="bttn"><a href="#" role="button">Practice Now</a></button>
               </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="flex-item">
        <div class="flex-item-inner">
               <div class="homepage-div homepage-div-shadow">
                <img class="homepage-div-icon"/>
                <h2>Heading</h2>
                <h6>Sub-Heading</h6>
                <p>This is responsive paragraph. Text would not move out of div as below .</p>
                <button class="bttn"><a href="#" role="button">Practice Now</a></button>
               </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="flex-item">
        <div class="flex-item-inner">
               <div class="homepage-div homepage-div-shadow">
                <img class="homepage-div-icon"/>
                <h2>Heading</h2>
                <h6>Sub-Heading</h6>
                <p>This is responsive paragraph. Text would not move out of div as below .</p>
                <button class="bttn"><a href="#" role="button">Practice Now</a></button>
               </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

here is css divs are not showing properly on tab and mobile devices and i want to decreae the padding and margin:



    .homepage-div-shadow
    {
        padding: 20px;
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px 1px #cccccc;
        border: solid 1px #cccccc;
        border-radius: 2px;
    }

    .homepage-div-icon{
        background-image: url("image.png");
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
    }
    .homepage-div a
    {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    .homepage-div h2{
        font-size: 28px;
        opacity: 0.90;
        font-weight: 600;
        margin: 5%;
        margin-bottom: 6px;
    }
    .homepage-div h6{
        font-size: 17px;
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        opacity: 0.6;
    }
    @media(min-width: 769px) {
        .flex-container {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }


        .flex-container .flex-item {
            flex: 1 0 50%;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 1024px) {
        .flex-container .flex-item {
            flex: 1 0 25%;
        }
    }

        .flex-item-inner {
            padding: 25px;
            margin: 20px;
            background-color: white;
        }
```

Here is the demo link: [testfellow](https://testfellow.com/)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
What have you tried, what piece of code do you need help with

Comment: Sounds like you're just asking for someone to do the work for you instead of guiding you on how to do it. Also, refer to @Joeri comment.

Answer (score 0):

Hope the solution below helps. I have just tried to mimic the scenario where there are a certain number of `div` s. And as per your question and requirement, have:
1. Followed mobile-first approach.
2. For mobile devices, each `div` should come in separate lines.
3. For tabs (at your breakpoint: 769px and above), two `div`s should come in a line.
4. For desktops (at your breakpoint: 1024px and above), four `div`s should come in a line.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #2980b9;
}

.flex {
  max-width: 80%;
}

.flex-item {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 5em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 2% auto;
  width: 25%;
}

@media(min-width: 769px) {
  .flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .flex-item {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media(min-width: 1024px) {
  .flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .flex-item {
    width: 25%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item "></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item "></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: not working; i want to show 4 divs for desktop and 2 on tab and 1 on mobile fully responsive. there are lot of padding and margin you can see the above demo link